# Trigger touch callout on iOS/android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web, callout

I would like to know if there is any possibility to trigger the "Save Image" touch callout on iOS and Android with Javascript. The callout is triggered by a longpress, but even if I try to simulate this, it won't work.

I would like to achieve something likes this:

```
jQuery('img').openCallout();
```

So far I tried this:

**jQuery:** `jQuery('img').contextmenu();`
**jQuery Mobile:** `jQuery('img').taphold();`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,*this* is *possible* using the `jquery mobile` as mentioned in the [docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html),using the [taphold](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event.(*Other events, I didn't try*)

As illustrated in this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pritishvaidya/102r5ho3/)**  (Till now tested in the following as shown [here](https://jquerymobile.com/browser-support/1.4/))

```
$(function() {
  $("div.box").bind("taphold", tapholdHandler);

  function tapholdHandler(event) {
    alert('Do you want to save the image or however it works in ipad');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = "http://i.imgur.com/JzdY53y.jpg";
    a.download = 'JzdY53y.jpg';
    alert("goes till here1"); // just a check
    a.click();
    alert("goes til here 2"); //just a check
  }
});
```

Comment: But in this case it just downloads the image and doesn't show the callout as in my picture above?

Comment: yea in chrome it downloads the picture without asking but this is just an example in which i have appended the `a` tag since i have no platform to test in the ios device.//This is justa reference to the fact that the taphold function works.